# How to get cart items at creating new order in the backend?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, backend

I've tried to load all items from the backend order.

Example:

```
$quote->getAllItems();
```

It works fine in the frontend, but not in the backend.
I've googled so much, as i can see there is no solution for this problem?
I need the items, because otherwise i can't get successful response from an external api.

Also it should run from magento 1.4+ CE.

Comment: Base on what your trying to do, it may be easier to use an observer so could you provide more information on what your tying to accomplish.

Comment: You want items of the current quote or of a particular order in admin?

Comment: @huzefam: That´s right. I need the value and all products of the order.

Comment: i still cant get..where are you trying to access the current order items on the order view page in admin??

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the question. But now i already solved the problem. i executed the code in a frontend controller. i did not know that i need to execute it in a backend controller. so sorry, my bad. but thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

Comment: It´s not even working :( I open the site in a popup, could this be the problem? I don´t think so, why should it? :( So, "adminhtml/session_quote" is empty for magento, he will create a new instance and then register it. But why?

Comment: You *are* trying to access items during admin "create order" activity, right?

Comment: hey, that´s right. i already solved the problem, see at comments on my question. thanks for help! :)